# How to get cell reference from range object in Excel using VB.net?

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel, vba

I have :

```
Dim cell As Excel.Range = sheet.Range("A2")

Console.WriteLine("Cell references to = " + ????? )
```

**What should I replace ????? with to get A2 printed in its place ?**

Please help !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `cell.Address(false, false)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Address property of the Range object, but you'll have to strip the '$' from it, as it returns the address in format "$A$2".

Hope this helps.